# SignalR Cannot re-call start of asynchronous method

Tags: c#, xamarin, signalr, webrtc

I have an issue which appears the be an `async` \ `await` issue but I am having a hard time tracking it down. Here is the problem, we are using Xamarin Android with SignalR implementing a WebRtc video conferencing system.

During the initial negotiations with WebRtc we recieve signals between the parties to setup the `offer` \ `answer` and the `IceCandidates` we recieve and process the first three candidates quickly, however the fourth seems the cause an Error on the `HubConnection`. Here is the exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot re-call start of asynchronous method while a previous call is still in progress.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse (System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0

Now this is on the 4th receive of an IceCandidate (given by the log output)

```
onIceCandidate: {"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1532951ed4f3bc58106a9d8d563c6ab7 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.118 1104 typ host","sdpMid":"","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
onIceCandidate: {"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1532951ed4f3bc58106a9d8d563c6ab7 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.1.118 34462 typ host","sdpMid":"","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
onIceCandidate: {"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:94378da69e185ca5371cdd7e0b75d8cf 1 udp 1694498815 59.167.62.173 1104 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.118 rport 1104","sdpMid":"","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
onIceCandidate: {"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:94378da69e185ca5371cdd7e0b75d8cf 1 udp 1694498815 59.167.62.173 34462 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.118 rport 34462","sdpMid":"","sdpMLineIndex":1}}
```

Now the calling methods look as below:

```
/// <summary>
/// handles the on ice candidates event
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
async void onIceCandidate(LinkCandidateArgs args)
{
    var rootJObject = new JObject();
    var candidateObject = new JObject();

    var cadString = args.Candidate.SdpCandidateAttribute;
    if (cadString.StartsWith("a="))
        cadString = cadString.Substring("a=".Length);

    candidateObject.Add("candidate", cadString);
    candidateObject.Add("sdpMid", "");
    candidateObject.Add("sdpMLineIndex", args.Candidate.SdpMediaIndex);

    rootJObject.Add("candidate", candidateObject);

    var payload = rootJObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

    Log.Debug(App.TAG, "onIceCandidate: " + payload);
    await this.sendSignal(args.PeerId, payload);
}

/// <summary>
/// sends a signal back to the hub client
/// </summary>
/// <param name="connectionId"></param>
/// <param name="payload"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task sendSignal(string connectionId, string payload)
{
    await this.proxy.Invoke("SendSignal", payload, connectionId);
}
```

Now the method `onIceCandidate(LinkCandidateArgs args)` is an event handler that is fired every time an IceCandidate is added to the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage the figure this out shortly after and figured it was best to post an answer. The problem here came from two area's. First off after reviewing some of the SignalR help guides I came across the configuration property for a client

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;`

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#maxconnections

The guide states:

> In WPF clients, you might have to increase the maximum number of
>   concurrent connections from its default value of 2. The recommended
>   value is 10.

Now I am not 100% sure what the Xamarin Android limit is however this seemed to have helped resolve the issue.

Secondly I removed the `async` \ `await` from the methods `onIceCandidate` and `sendSignal` it appears as if the awaiter was causing issues with the underlying `HttpWebRequest` and throwing an error. Now I am still not 100% sure why this was happening however I no longer receive the errors on the `HubConnection`.

Hope this helps someone in the future.